# Firebase in app messaging for React Native not displaying

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have an Android React Native app which uses Firebase. It now requires in app messaging for which I have followed the [instructions here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=android)

When I send a test message from Firebase using the instance id for my Android emulator, I get the following when restarting the app:

```sh
2019-11-21 15:26:43.472 6075-6075/? I/FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Instance ID xxxxx
2019-11-21 15:26:43.746 6075-6075/? I/FIAM.Headless: Setting display event listener
2019-11-21 15:26:43.752 6075-6075/? I/FIAM.Headless: went foreground
2019-11-21 15:26:43.759 6075-6110/? I/FIAM.Headless: Forcing fetch from service rather than cache. Test Device: true | App Fresh Install: true
2019-11-21 15:26:43.780 6075-6110/? W/FIAM.Headless: Recoverable exception while reading cache: /data/user/0/example.app/files/fiam_impressions_store_file: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-11-21 15:26:43.795 6075-6110/? I/FIAM.Headless: Fetching campaigns from service.
2019-11-21 15:26:49.556 6075-6110/example.app I/FIAM.Headless: Successfully fetched 1 messages from backend
```

Judging by the last line, a message has been received. However nothing is displayed in the app on the emulator.

The only change I made was to use an older version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` so that the gradle files synced correctly. My `build.gradle` file:

```sh
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.6'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
```

Is there something else I need to do in addition to the above instructions?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

According not to the firebase official page but to the react-native-firebase, the dependency should be like this:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.2.0'
}
```

link:https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/in-app-messaging/android

I could succeed to send the in-app message to a test device. But I could not succeed to send in-app message to apps on google play. Don't know why.

Update:
I just duplicated the message campaign and sent it again, then it works on app on google play.